# White noise with non-constant variance

Tags: stochastic-processes, variance, stochastic-analysis, noise

Is there a name for white noise that has non-constant variance? I have some examples from experimental data where the variance of the white noise increases with time. However, I am not sure how to model this.

Comment: "Non stationary"

Comment: First have you tried to transform the data? Like model changes instead of levels or take logs?

Comment: @fes yeah, that it exactly what my question is getting at. I am trying to determine if there is another way of looking at the problem. Any ideas?